# What is the O(n) time algorithm for Union and intersection of two sorted arrays?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity

The sets a and b have n elements each given in the form of sorted arrays. Present an O(n) time algorithm to compute a union b and a intersection b.

Answer (score 0):

You just have two pointers to each array and you are always moving the one which is lesser or same.

Then if you get two same numbers at both pointers you get intersection. If you want union, you just put the one you have moved. (and if you dont want duplicities for the same numbers, you just have to check if you have already added that number)